# How to call an optional protocol method?

Tags: swift

I have a class that conforms to my own protocol that has optional methods. The reference to that class's object is also an optional. In other words, the object *may* be present and it *may* have implemented the method in question. But how do I call it?
I have code like this:

```
if let theDelegate = delegate {
    if let result = theDelegate.delegateMethod() {
    }
}
```

but Xcode complains that the "value of optional type '(()->())?' not unwrapped". it wants me to change the second half of line 2 in the example to "theDelegate.delegateMethod!()", but force unwrapping defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do. How am I supposed to call this method? Note that my method has no parameters or return values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID284), optional methods should be called like this:

```
if let theDelegate = delegate {
    if let result = theDelegate.delegateMethod?() {
    }else {
        // delegateMethod not implemented
    }
}
```

> Optional property requirements, and optional method requirements that return a value, will always return an optional value of the appropriate type when they are accessed or called, to reflect the fact that the optional requirement may not have been implemented.